# How to combine date and time in field calculator in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, datetime

I want to simulate the travel path based on data points generated by my farm tractor, which is equipped a GPS receiver (I want to know where it starts and where it ends). Unfortunately the generated data points are not labelled sequential IDs.

In ArcGIS, I have two columns `Date` and `Time` on the attribute table that I can refer to as sequence and then use `points to lines` to generate lines.

Both `Date` and `Time` are `string` field:

[image]

Maybe I should combine two columns into one? I've tried few times inputting `Time` as `Line Field` and `Date` as `Sort Field` but turns out `warning001059`.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of your intended output? Have you considered sorting first by date and then by time? Then you can simply reference the OID. http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/sort.htm

Comment: @GoldenJiang Could you please [edit] your question and provide an example of your intended output?

Comment: Question edited. Hope that makes sense. @Midavalo

Comment: If it's a single run a day you can use date as lineid for points to line tool

Comment: Time can be line I'd under no circumstances

Comment: Convert your date and time to UTC, that way it's only one field with a really big number (double). You can convert in python by creating a datetime object http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_date_time.htm and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79797/how-do-i-convert-local-time-to-utc-in-python... do you want to script this or do it in the field calculator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new column with `DATE` format

[image]

Run Field Calculator on it, select Python parser, and enter the following expression:

```py
datetime.datetime.strptime("{} {}".format(!MyDate!, !MyTime!), "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

where `MyDate` is the name of your date field, and `MyTime` is the name of your time field.

This will populate your new field with the datetime which is sortable.

[image]

**NOTE:** This will fail on the fields with invalid dates like your `2000-00-00` in your screenshot above.  You'll need to tidy that data, or select around it when you run the Field Calculator

Comment: Why my `New_Date` field only gives dates, no times? @Midavalo

Comment: @GoldenJiang is that on every record, or just some?

Comment: @GoldenJiang is this a Shapefile?  Shapefile date fields do not store time.  File geodatabase will store the time as shown in my answer.  Can the data be converted to file geodatabase first?

Comment: My bad, I didn't put the file in a geodatabase ... Now `New_Date` contains `10/062016 1:32:30 a.m.` etc. But I am getting a list of `WARNING001059: Not enough points to create a line for value 2016-05-30 01:58:40.` when I run `points to lines`.  @Midavalo

Comment: So I should use `New_Date` as `Sort Field`. Great thanks @Midavalo

Comment: @GoldenJiang yes that's correct

Comment: Can you please explain `datetime.datetime.strptime` like why use `datetime` function twice? Can you also please explain `"{} {}"`? Thank you

Comment: @Arthur_Morgan `datetime.datetime` is due to the module `datetime` also having a class called `datetime` - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66321945/why-do-i-need-to-write-datetime-two-times

Comment: @Arthur_Morgan regarding the `{} {}` have a look at the documentation for str.format() https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings

Comment: Cheers for the quick response.